# confusing with counting principles....

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Below are the example , please explain it to me, im really confusing . Thank A lot

By using only 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7 to form three 2-digit numbers and a 1 digit number, the total of the four numbers must be euqal to 100.
 a) Find the number of ways to fulfil the above rquirement if all the digits must be used.
 b) Find the largest value of the 2-digit number that can be formed in (a).

Comment: Are you unsure what the description intends? For example, the three 2-digit numbers 12, 35, 46 and the 1-digit number 7 add to 100. You're being asked to count how many such answers there are in part (a).

Answer (score 1):

If

$ab + cd + ef + g = 100$

then

$10(a+c+e) + (b+d+f+g) = 100$

but we know

$a + b + c + d + e + f + g = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = 28$

so

$b+d+f+g = 28 - (a + c + e)$

substituting gives

$10(a+c+e) + 28 - (a + c + e) = 100$

so

$9(a+c+e) = 72$

and

$a+c+e = 8$

$2+3+4=9>8$ so one of $a,c,e$ must be $1$. The other two therefore add to $7$ and can only be $2$ and $5$, or $3$ and $4$.

So $\{a,c,e\}  = \{1,2,5\}$, or $\{1,3,4\}$

and $\{b,d,f,g\}  = \{3,4,6,7\}$, or $\{2,5,6,7\}$

We are only concerned with what the numbers are, and not their ordering, so we can asumme that $a = 1, b =2, c=5$ or $a = 1, b =3, c=4$ and see how many ways we can choose $b,d,f,g$ to go with them.

For each $\{b,d,f,g\}$ we have $4$ choices for $b$, $3$ choices for $d$, $2$ choices for $f$ and the last number becomes $g$. So $2 * (4 * 3* 2) = 48$ ways.

The largest two digit number is formed by pairing the largest possible value for $a,c,e \;(5)$ and the largest possible value for $b,d,f,g\;(7)$, so $57$.